# Como substituir o "NAN" por 0 em Javascript

Tags: javascript

Bom, o que pretendia era substituir a palavra "NaN" em javascript por 0.

Já procurei alguns tópicos aqui no stackoverflow mas nenhum me ajudou.

Qual seria o código para fazer esta mudança?

Obrigado.

@EDIT:

Tentei fazer desta forma, mas agora os valores estão me a dar undefined:

Peço desculpa, se realmente eu estou a cometer algum erro, mas eu ainda sou novato em js e tenho o mesmo "raciocinio" do php.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<script>

 function calcular(){


    var valor1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('bikemountain').value);
    var valor2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('bikesenhora').value);
    var valor3 = parseInt(document.getElementById('bikecrianca').value);


    if(valor1 == null){

        var totalvalores = valor2 + valor3;


    }

    if(valor2 == null){

        var totalvalores = valor1 + valor3;
    }
    if(valor3 == null){

        var totalvalores = valor1 + valor2;

    }











      document.getElementById('precoapagar').innerHTML = totalvalores;





 }

setInterval("calcular()",100);

</script>
<form action="verifica1.php" method="post">

<h3><b>Informações Pessoais</b></h3>
<br>
Nome: <input type="text" name="nome" required>

<br>
<br>
Tipo de Documento de Identifcação:
<select>
  <option value="cartaocidadao">Cartão de Cidadão</option>
  <option value="bilheteidentidade">Bilhete de Identidade</option>
  <option value="passaporte">Passaporte</option>
  <option value="cartaconducao">Carta de Condução</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
Telemóvel: <input type="telemovel" required>
<br>
<br>

<b><h3>Levantamento</h3></b>



Número de Bicicletas tipo Mountain Bike: <input type="text" name="bikemountain" id="bikemountain">
<br>
<br>
Número de Bicicletas de Senhora: <input type="text" name="bikesenhora" id="bikesenhora">
<br>
<br>
Número de Bicicletas de Criança: <input type="text" name="bikecrianca" id="bikecrianca">

<br>

<br>
Dia de Levantamento:
<input type="date" name="dialevantamento" required>
<br>
<br>
Hora de Levantamento
<input type="time" name="horalevantamento" required>
<br>
<br>
Tempo Desejado:
<input type='number' name="tempodesejado" onblur="calcular()" id="tempodesejado" step=1 required>
<select id="tipo" name="tipo">
  <option value="horas">Horas</option>
  <option value="dias">Dias</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<br>




Preço a Pagar: <span id="precoapagar">0</span>€

<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Prosseguir!">
</form>

</html>
```

Comment: Qual é a sua função ?

Comment: Em que ponto vc deseja fazer o teste?

Comment: Eu quero fazer do tipo, ou seja se a input 1 nao tiver nada, a variavel totalvalores é so o valor 2+ valor3 ou seja calcula so os outros 2, e o mesmo raciocinio com os outros todos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Olha este exemplo:

```
var x = 10 / 'foo';
var y = x || 0;
console.log(x, y);
// dá: NaN 0
```

Ou seja `NaN` valida como false. Nesse exemplo ele irá repor o valor também no caso de dar `0` no valor do `x`. Mas é simples. Se quiseres uma verificação mais cuidada podes fazer:

```
var y = Number.isNaN(x) ? 0 : x;
```

Para aplicares no teu problema onde queres somar valores e alguns deles são `NaN` podes fazer assim:

```
var valor1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('bikemountain').value, 10);
var valor2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('bikesenhora').value, 10);
var valor3 = parseInt(document.getElementById('bikecrianca').value, 10);

var totalvalores = [valor1, valor2, valor3].reduce(function(total, nr) {
    return total + (nr || 0);
}, 0);

document.getElementById('precoapagar').innerHTML = totalvalores;
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/omLkqbe9/

---

Dando uma olhada à logica que tens no código acho que podias fazer mais DRY e sem esse setInterval a correr a cada 50ms... assim:

```
var inputs = ['bikemountain', 'bikesenhora', 'bikecrianca'].map(function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
});
inputs.forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('keyup', calcular);
});
function calcular() {

    var totalvalores = inputs.reduce(function(total, el) {
        return total + (Number(el.value) || 0);
    }, 0);

    document.getElementById('precoapagar').innerHTML = totalvalores;
}
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/omLkqbe9/1/

Comment: QUando utilizo isso, a minha função deixa de funcionar. Mas quando aparece simplesmente Nan volta dnv a funcionar.

Comment: @Gonçalo tens um exemplo?

Comment: Vou colocar o meu código na pergunta.

Comment: Código postado.

Comment: @Gonçalo juntei mais info na resposta

Comment: Isso mesmo! Obrigado.

Comment: Sergio um pequeno aparte, se eu quiser multiplicar esta parte "var totalvalores = [valor1, valor2, valor3].reduce(function(total, nr) {
    return total + (nr || 0);" pela variável preco, como poderei fazer?

Comment: @Gonçalo queres multiplicar cada um ou o total?

Comment: O total daquilo tudo, quero multiplicar pelo preco. Abri uma pergunta aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131996/como-multiplicar-uma-variavel-por-outra/131999?noredirect=1#comment274616_131999

Comment: @Gonçalo ok, não tinha visto. Vou responder lá.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer:

```
a = a || 0
```

...que vai converter qualquer valor "falsey" de a para 0.

Valores "falsey" são:

> false
>  null 
> undefined 
> 0 
> "" ( empty string ) 
> NaN ( Not a Number )

Ou assim se preferir:

```
a = a ? a : 0;
```

...que terá o mesmo resultado acima.

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540397/convert-nan-to-0-in-javascript)

Comment: QUando utilizo isso, a minha função deixa de funcionar. Mas quando aparece simplesmente Nan volta dnv a funcionar

Comment: @Gonçalo Coloca seu código na pergunta.

Comment: Código Postado.